# How to define a color in matplotlib-plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried the following example to draw a line with RGB color definition:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, color='#FF0000')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

but the resulting image was just blank! (Except the axes)

How to define a RGB color in a plot statement?

Comment: The line doesn't appear because you need to give at least 2 x and 2 y coordinates to draw a line.

Comment: @DavidG: Of course. I am stupid.... Create a simple answer to accept your solution....

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `plot` with incorrect arguments. X and y should be iterables:

```
ax.plot((0, 0), (0.5, 0.5), color='#FF0000')
```

Comment: Technically still wouldn't be able to see the line as the coordinates are the same, but I'm nust nitpicking :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifiy the color correctly, the problem is that you need at least 2 `x`, and 2 `y` coordinates to draw a line. The documentation can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

```
ax.plot([0, 1], [0.5, 1], color='#FF0000')
```

**Note**: probably due to reducing down to a MCVE, but the coordinates also can't be the same as you can't draw a line from a point to itself